# RESTful webservice with RMI

Tags: java, rest, rmi

Hi i'm wondering if is possible to make a RESTful webservice with RMI, for example.. RMI server and RESTful client, and how I would do it?
thanks in advance

Comment: I think this can help you which your Q  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702409/rmi-vs-rest-service) and this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100993/rmi-vs-web-services-whats-best-for-java2java-remoting)

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely possible - although I am not sure how it can be useful.

The RESTful client can send the REST query to an intermediate Rest/RMI converter which converts a REST query to RMI and forwards it to an RMI client. The RMI client will forward the query to the RMI sever and then respond once it gets the response from the RMI server.

Something like below -

> **[REST Client]** --(REST query)--> **[Rest/RMI converter/RMI Client]**--> (RMI request) --> **[RMI Server]**
>
> **[REST Client]** <---(REST response) <-- **[Rest/RMI converter/RMI Client]**--- (RMI response) <-- **[RMI Server]**

Comment: An RMI client can't receive requests, but the converter can *be* the RMI client.

Comment: Edited - please see now.